# print gender in java from this link list?

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<User> list=new LinkedList<User>();

        list.add(new User(1, "Haidar Ali", "male", true));
        list.add(new User(2, "Mehmood Usmani", "male", false));
        list.add(new User(3, "Ayesha  Abbasi", "female", true));    
        list.add(new User(4,"Nilofur","female",true));
    }
}
```

(how can i write the code which print the male gender or female gender form mix list code above)

Comment: Can we see the user class?

Answer (score 2):

- Add a getter method for the `gender` property in `User` with appropriate access (if not already there)
- Iterate over your `List`
- Invoke the getter method to print the gender

Answer (score 1):

If you have getter/setter method in your User class than you can simply call getter methods to get the properties value. If you don't have than simple put getter/setter in your User Class.

For iterating the list -

```
for (User user : list) {
   String userGender = user.getGender(); // call the getter method of gender from User class
   System.out.println(userGender );
}
```

the same way you can access the other properties of your User Class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print males then

```
for (int i = 0; i < list; i++) {
    if (list.get(i).gender.equals("male") {
        System.out.println(list.get(i).name);
    }
}
```

If gender is private then create public setter/getter and do it like user.getGender()

Comment: You're assuming the `gender` property of `User` is accessible and never `null`.

Comment: Where have you seen the `gender` attribute? What should that work if it wasn't eve accessible?

Comment: Since the list implementation doesn't support random access, this is an n^2 algorithm.  A for-each loop would be better.

Comment: As User is not provided I assume there is a gender property or something similar. This is just an example, it can be improved a hundred ways (nullcheck, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Your user class needs a way to get the gender. Let's say you have a `getGender` method. Then you could do:

```
for (User user : list) {
   String gender = user.getGender(); 
   System.out.println(gender);
}
```